# Mean and Standard Deviation of x>=5 of 10000 data points binomial(10, 1/4)

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation, binomial-theorem

I have a data range of 10,000 points as per:

```
data = rbinom(10000, size=10, prob=1/4)
```

I need to find the mean and standard deviation of the data values `>=5`.

There are approx 766 values as per:

```
sum(data >=5)
```

`sum` (or any other approach I can think of) produces a `TRUE/FALSE` and cannot be used within a `mean` or `sd` calculation. How do I divide up the actual values?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the values of `data` which are greater than or equal to 5, rather than just a logical vector telling you *if* the values of `data` are greater than or equal to 5, you need to do `data[data >= 5]`.

So we can do:

```r
data = rbinom(10000, size=10, prob=1/4)

mean(data[data >= 5])
#> [1] 5.298153

sd(data[data >= 5])
#> [1] 0.5567141
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(. >= 5) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(.),
            sd = sd(.))
```

Output:

```
      mean        sd
1 5.297092 0.5815554
```

##### Data

```
data = rbinom(10000, size=10, prob=1/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TRUE` and `FALSE` values can be used in `mean()`, `sum()`, `sd()`, etc... as they have numerical values 0 and 1, respectively.

```r
set.seed(456)
data = rbinom(10000, size=10, prob=1/4)
mean(data >= 5)
#> [1] 0.0779
sum(data >= 5)
#> [1] 779
sd(data >= 5)
#> [1] 0.2680276
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I read the question as getting the mean and sd of all the values in data that are greater than or equal to 5

Comment: @AllanCameron sorry, I read it as wanting the `mean(data >= 5)` rather than `mean(data[data >= 5])`.   I'll leave the answer here for now, but re-reading the question, I suspect you're right.